# JPA Query works only native

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here is my repository:

```
public interface MachineRepository extends JpaRepository<Machine, Integer> {

    @Query(value="select m.name FROM Machine m", nativeQuery = true)
    Set<SomeName> getAllMachineTypes();
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface SomeName {
    String getName();
}
```

Model:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Machine")
public class Machine {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class MachineService {

    @Autowired
    MachineRepository machineRepository;

    public Set<SomeName> getAllMachines(){
        return machineRepository.getAllMachines();
    }
```

Controller:

```
    @Autowired
    MachineService machineService;
    @RequestMapping("/")
        public String findMachines(){
            Set<SomeName> machines = machineService.getAllMachines();
            for (SomeName mch: machines
                 ) {
                System.out.println(mch.getName());
            }

            //...
        }
```

When I run as it is, it prints the name to the console. But when I change nativeQuery to false (or remove it because it is false by default):

```
public interface MachineRepository extends JpaRepository<Machine, Integer> {

    @Query(value="select m.name FROM Machine m", nativeQuery = false)
    Set<SomeName> getAllMachineTypes();
}
```

Then I don't get any output.
Since I don't want to use nativeQuery, I would like to ask how to make it work without it.

Comment: what happens if you change your query to this: `select m FROM Machine m` whch is actually findAll.

Comment: no output for nativeQuery=false and java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'm' in 'field list' for nativeQuery=true

Comment: `m.name` is a String, yet you return a Set of `SomeName`. This cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public interface MachineRepository extends JpaRepository<Machine, Integer> {

    @Query(value="select m.name FROM Machine m")
    List<String> getAllMachineTypes();
}
```

because `m.name` is a String.